# A stratified data.frame results in zero rows/observations in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, row

I stratified my `data.frame` (with 80 columns and 10.000 rows) by a factor variable `school` with two levels (`0: high, 1:low`) using the following command:

```
high.school=data.frame[which(data.frame$school==0) , ]
low.school=data.frame[which(data.frame$school==1) , ]
```

But it resulted in two `data.frames` with all 80 columns, but with `0 rows`. Why the rows are not being considered?

Thanks!

Comment: check the variable name- `school` . you may have written it wrong.

Comment: Is the name of your data frame really `data.frame`? It is probably not a good idea to use `data.frame` as an object name. Also, could you please show us the results of `str` applied to your data frame?

Comment: It's written correct. It's just a generic name, my data frame doesn't call data.frame.

Comment: My data frame has numeric and factors characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer-Why use which?
Lets try this out.

```
> DF=NULL
> DF$school=as.factor(sample(c(0,1),10000,T))
> DF=as.data.frame(DF)
> head(DF)
  school
1      0
2      0
3      1
4      1
5      0
6      1
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ school: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
```

So you see the factor value of school is 1,2 while the factor level is 0,1 
Now try the below

```
> df2=DF[DF$school==1,]
> df3=DF[DF$school==0,]
> str(df2)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
> str(df3)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> head(df2)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
Levels: 0 1
> head(df3)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
```